# Typescript output file for definition files is wrong

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to build my project with ts > js files and the ts definition files along sign the js files when compiled.

Currently the files are building properly, but the .d.ts files are being put inside `dist/src` folder then with the correct paths. How can I get these to be compiled next to their js parents. for example `dist/components/Select/index.d.ts` rather than the incorrect way: `dist/src/components/Select/index.d.ts`

## package.json

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && npx tsc && NODE_ENV=production babel src/components --out-dir dist --extensions '.tsx' --presets @babel/preset-typescript --presets @babel/preset-env --ignore __tests__,__snapshots__,__mocks__,stories.js,**/*.test.tsx",
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "rootDirs": [
      "src",
      "stories",
      "config"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    // Ensure that .d.ts files are created by tsc, but not .js files
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    // Ensure that Babel can safely transpile files in the TypeScript project
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "docs"
  ]
}
```

## built files

```
dist
dist/FormGenerator
dist/Input
dist/Link
dist/List
dist/MoneyFormat
dist/Select
dist/Select/index.js
dist/Select/Select.js
dist/src
dist/src/components
dist/src/components/FormGenerator
dist/src/components/Input
dist/src/components/Link
dist/src/components/List
dist/src/components/MoneyFormat
dist/src/components/Select
dist/src/components/Select/index.d.ts
dist/src/components/Select/Select.d.ts
dist/src/components/Svg
dist/src/components/TemplateComponent
dist/src/components/Text
dist/src/components/index.d.ts
dist/src/themes
dist/src/setupTests.d.ts
dist/Svg
dist/TemplateComponent
dist/test-utils
dist/Text
dist/index.js
```

## root folder structure

```
.github
.husky
.storybook
.vscode
dist
node_modules
reports
src
test-utils
.codacy.yml
.editorconfig
.env
.env.local
.eslintignore
.eslintrc
.gitignore
.npmrc
.prettierignore
.prettierrc
jest.config.js
package.json
README.md
setupFile.js
tsconfig.json
yarn.lock
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. If you could provide me with some feedback I will happily update the question. So please let me know how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any .ts file outside the src dir? If so, then the compiler is also compiles that file and the final folder structure will include src.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question to show the root dir, there are no ts files. Though there are some inside the `test-utiles` folder which could very well be causing the issue. I'll play with that.

Comment: i also have a test folder outside src but that is added inside the "exclude" property of tsconfig.build.json.

This way, ts will not compile the tests at build, since tests are no needed in the final build.